# Tarraform iam policy resource definition conditionally based on variable

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

Is there an option in terraform to set resource, as part of AWS IAM policy definition, conditionally.  So, to set  one Resource value if variable is True, or another Resource when variable is False?

This is my policy:

```
 policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxx:key/${var.platform_development_mode} ? * : ${var.platform_vault_kms_id}"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I want part after 'key' -

```
${var.platform_development_mode} ? * : ${var.platform_vault_kms_id}
```

to make conditional, to take either '*', or exact key_id value.

Thank you,
Miroslav

Comment: I suggest you try with workspaces, that way you can use maps, i.e. you could use `var.kms_id[terraform.workspace]` and use a dev key for development and a prod key for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxx:key/${var.platform_development_mode ? "*" : var.platform_vault_kms_id}"
        }
    ]
}
```